# How do I redirect the blog links of my Wordpress site to a new subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, url, subdomain, redirect

My current site (www.cooksmarts.com) is on Wordpress. We are launching a rails app (which will be hosted by a service like Heroku / Engine Yard) and are considering housing the app in our root domain. If so, we'd move my blog to to a subdomain, like blog.cooksmarts.com. Right now all the blog entries are updated in the subfolder www.cooksmarts.com/cs-blog. How do I redirect only calls for that subfolder to the new subdomain? For example if any existing link pointed to http://www.cooksmarts.com/cs-blog/2013/03/Chicken-Recipe, it would automatically re-direct to http://blog.cooksmarts.com/2013/03/Chicken-Recipe

Comment: It's definitely possible. You would need to use a 'Wildcard Redirect' for your domain. This would redirect your root links to your subdomain links that have the same url permalink (i.e. as you have stated in your question).

Comment: Checkout out this railscast on subdomains: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: @Charles Thanks for posting that link. Unfortunately, I'm going to keep my blog functionality using WordPress so it wouldn't be part of my Rails app

Answer (score 0):

create subdomain in cs-blog folder

simply add rewite rule in your htaccess file like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cooksmarts.com/cs-blog/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cooksmarts.com/cs-blog/
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog.cooksmarts.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

then goto wordpress admin setting and change

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)
  by blog.cooksmarts.com

Comment: Hi Piyush, I'm confused as to why I would create a subdomain in the cs-blog folder? And where do I load the htaccess file (assuming I won't be using Wordpress anymore in the root domain)?

Comment: when you creat subdomain it ask for folder where you want to locate this subdomain where you store all your files of your subdomain.check it [link](http://www.timestips.com/images/subdomain.png) you need to add folder where your wordpress blog data.

Comment: add these three line of code in your .htaccess file in your root directory so it can redirect rewrite url your blog visiter to subdomain